# What is the Guaranteed Lifetime of a Azure Storage API Version (API SLA)

Tags: azure, azure-storage

After reading the Azure Storage SLA ( https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/storage/v1_0/ ), it did not find where it states how long we can count on an API being valid. If I am building a device, I have essentially two choices, each with its specific trade-offs:

1. Over the air updates.
2. Stable API over the expected lifetime of the device ( > 10 years in any case). i.e. having a stable API contract so my software won't break due to API changes.

I'm looking for an answer to item 2 here with Azure Storage APIs via the Azure Storage Client Library (or, if not, native REST API or whatever).

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know, Microsoft is not providing guarantees on API immutability.  They do retire old versions.  They're retiring Storage API from 2009 a year from now.  So, that makes it 6yrs?

Comment: Thanks. I hope this is not the answer! :-) Microsoft was always good about supporting things for the long-haul, and the last time I talked with some IoT-Services devs this was a primary "feature" focus in that space anyway...

Comment: It is kind of getting into "Opinion" category but I would not take a dependency on the the storage client library or REST API at the device level. I would rather manage it at my services level and expose my services at the device level where things are in my control because as mentioned by @Igorek, Azure **will update** the APIs because it is an evolving platform and that **will make** some of the features obsolete.

Comment: Thanks. Now writing a facade to encapsulate evolution :-) We could consider versioning of APIs an option so not everyone in the world must write a facade.